# Adding new Node to Cluster using Ambari Cluster Install wizard

Tags: cluster-computing, ambari, selectnodes, analytics-for-apache-hdp, bigdata

I've initially installed 2 slave nodes(node01, node02) cluster using Ambari Cluster Install wizard successfully.

My Ambari Server is running on other node ( node 00 ).

Problem is at the time of install wizard i gave only 2 slave node (because it asked me to enter the target hosts)

so i assumed and gave node 01, node 02(slaves (say)),

Eventually by default node 01 and node 02 behaved as master and slave (All the services/components were shared by these 2 nodes (node 01 and 02) and it went successfully and became 2 node cluster

Now what is my requirement is want to add node 00 (Ambari server is running) to make whole system as 3 node cluster and want to make node 00 as master (if there are any possibilities) and or else simply add and run few of services on it.

One thing all the services were shared between node 01 and node 02, so what services need to add for node 00.

shall i make node 00 as data node/name node/sec. name node? if yes how?

please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to recreate the structure by uninstalling and installing Ambari again. The second option is use Ambari Rest API calls using curl to disable then delete the component (this option is not there in Ambari UI, hence you need to use Rest API calls) then add it again from Ambari UI.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Using+APIs+to+delete+a+service+or+all+host+components+on+a+host

Before doing it, ensure you take backup of data and metadata files. I think you are may be using postgres for storing Ambari metadata and mysql for Hive & Derby fro oozie. You may need to do backup of metadata also.